# TypeScript loop over array of tuples

Tags: typescript

How do I loop over an array of tuples in TypeScript? e.g.

```
for (const [x, y] of [['a', 1], ['b', 2]]) {
  y + 1;
}
```

complains:

```
error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and '1'.
```

If I understand correctly, TypeScript infers type `(string | number)[][]` for the loop expression, which is why the loop variable `y` has type `string | number` although actually it can only ever have type `number`?

I think https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3369 is the issue that keeps TypeScript from inferring the suitable type. What is the current solution for looping over an array of tuples? [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real issue is that the type of `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]` is not a tuple type at all. It will be the array type `(string | number)[][]`. So when destructuring `x` and `y` will both be `string | number`. Typescript will only infer tuple in particular situations (like a type parameter constrained to an array, or an `as const` assertion).

If you use an `as const` assertion to get typescript to infer a tuple type and everything will work as expected:

```
for (const [x, y] of [['a', 1], ['b', 2]] as const) {
  y + 1;
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYewTgBAFAxiB2BnALhA2gDwDQQJ4F0IRh00ByAQzJwEZ8dyAjaiAJn0IsQjiWQEoIAbwBQEPBADUEGgG4RAXyA)

Comment: Awesome! I was unaware of `const` assertions: I've now added `as const` and `readonly [...]`/`readonly ...[]` to a bunch of code. Thank you!

BTW https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#const-assertions was the best resource I found on `const` assertions the `readonly` type modifier.

Answer (score 9):

Just add type annotations that TS should understand the structure. It can't infer from the set yet.

```
const array: [string, number][] = [['a', 1], ['b', 2]];

for (const [x, y] of array) {
  y + 1;
}
```

Additionally I like to mention that when dealing with 2 dimensional associations, the better data structure is a Map in my opinion:

```
const myMap = new Map<string, number>([['a', 1], ['b', 2]]);

for (const [x, y] of [...myMap]) {
  console.log(y + 1);
}
```

**Advanced: Custom iterables**

If the logic for the tuples is something consistent, then you can create your own iterable objects by using the `Symbol.iterator` famous symbol:

```
class TupleMaker implements Iterable<[string, number]> {
  private next = 0;
  constructor(private endsAt: number = 0) {}

  private increment(): void {
    this.next++;
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator](): Generator<[string, number]> {
    const alpha = Array.from(Array(26)).map((e, i) => i + 65);
    const alphabet = alpha.map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x).toLocaleLowerCase());
    while (this.next < this.endsAt) {
      yield [alphabet[this.next], this.next + 1];
      this.increment();
    }
  }
}

for (const [x, y] of new TupleMaker(13)) {
  console.log(y + 1);
}
```

They can be async too using `Symbol.asyncIterator`

Comment: Re: `Map`, assuming `x`s are distinct.

Comment: Yes, That's what I assumed based on a,b,c