# How to Declare and Destructure a Tuple Array in a for..of Loop in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, destructuring, for-of-loop

I have the following JavaScript code in a test file:

```js
for (let [input, expected] of [
  ['<h1>test</h1>', ['</h1>']],
  ['<h1><b>test</b></h1>', ['</h1>', '</b>']],
  ['<h1><b>test</b> lol</h1>', ['</h1>']],
]) {
  const result = functionToTest(input);
  for (let i in expected) {
    if (result[i] !== expected[i]) {
      throw Error("test failed")
    }
  }
}
```

TypeScript does not accept this code because `functionToTest` expects a `string` and TypeScript thinks that `input` has type `string | string[]`.

One thing that works is to put my test data in a separate variable and declare its type as a list of tuples:

```js
const testData: [string, string[]][] = [
  ['<h1>test</h1>', ['</h1>']],
  ['<h1><b>test</b></h1>', ['</h1>', '</b>']],
  ['<h1><b>test</b> lol</h1>', ['</h1>']],
]

for (let [input, expected] of testData) {
  const result = listClosingTagsAtEnd(input);
  for (let i in expected) {
    if (result[i] !== expected[i]) {
      throw Error("test failed")
    }
  }
}
```

However I would like *not* to have to create a variable to store data that I only need once. I liked it better when it was declared in the for loop.

I tried to do type declaration in the for loop with `let [input, expected]: [string, string[]] of` but I get the error `The left-hand side of a 'for...of' statement cannot use a type annotation.`.

I also tried to add `: [string, string[]]` *after* the declaration of the test data in the for loop but then TypeScript thinks I am using a [JavaScript label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

How can I have properly typed destructuration while keeping the declaration of test data inside the for loop?

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out myself by chance, just “trying random things”, so I wanted to post it to Stack Overflow in case other people have the same problem. Here is how you do it:

```js
for (let [input, expected] of <[string, string[]][]>[
  //                          ^--------------------^
  //                             type declaration
  ['<h1>test</h1>', ['</h1>']],
  ['<h1><b>test</b></h1>', ['</h1>', '</b>']],
  ['<h1><b>test</b> lol</h1>', ['</h1>']],
]) {
  const result = functionToTest(input);
  for (let i in expected) {
    if (result[i] !== expected[i]) {
      throw Error("test failed")
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Wow, found another solution on [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528358/3025740)! Just add `as const` after the literal:

```
for (let [input, expected] of [
  ['<h1>test</h1>', ['</h1>']],
  ['<h1><b>test</b></h1>', ['</h1>', '</b>']],
  ['<h1><b>test</b> lol</h1>', ['</h1>']],
] as const) {
//   ^---^
//    HERE
  const result = functionToTest(input);
  for (let i in expected) {
    if (result[i] !== expected[i]) {
      throw Error("test failed")
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, TypeScript considers that `input` has type `"<h1>test</h1>" | "<h1><b>test</b></h1>" | "<h1><b>test</b> lol</h1>"` for instance, which is ... the most exact description of `input`'s type indeed.

Comment: adding "as const" at the end, as suggested in your edit, fixed the problem for me. This is the best way that I found to fix Tupple's destructuring